NetSuite Email send with diff author
I am trying to send bulk email to multiple recipients but there is one problem which is I have to send the mail not my current user id I have to change current user id and give another how can  I achieve this
`
var  recipientEmails = [
    'singexample@gmail.com',
    's.example@example.tech',
   'example@example.tech',
   'example@example.tech'
];
email.sendBulk({
    author: -5, // here I want to put my custom email which erv76@gmail.com
    recipients: recipientEmails,
    subject: 'Sales order ',
    body: 'your sales order is created ',
    replyTo: 'accounts@netsuite.com'
});

`
author: -5, // here I want to put my custom email which erv76@gmail.com

author parameter accepts only an internal ID of an employee record and should not directly use the email address itself.
so, you can create an employee record using your email erv76@gmail.com and then use the internal ID of that employee record as the author. Also , you dont need to give login access to this employee record if you dont have to login.
Alternatively, if you prefer not to retain that employee record in your system, you can create a temporary employee record before sending the email and then delete that temporary record after sending the email.
